# remove \ufeff from a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When reading in rows from a csv file it always appends \ufeff to the beginning and aside from that it is fine. Instead of using DictReader the initial problem is that of course if i use:

```
r = unicodecsv.reader(f, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

the output comes into the python program in a completely different (list) format:

```
line: ['nickname', 'name', 'phone', 'address']
line: ['Harry', 'Harry James Potter', 'N/A', '4 Pivet Drive Little Whinging, Surrey']
line: ['Sirius', 'Sirius Black', 'N/A', '12 Grimald Place London']
line: []
```

Can somebody give me an example of how to turn these four **Lines** into a dictionary while using Line one as the dictionary headings?

- Secondly, Alternatively does any genius out there know how to conversely remove \ufeff once it is already in a dictionary like that. Even if I try like below (to pop the entire nickname from the dictionary because i don't even need it I already have each person's fullname) it acts like \ufeffnickname does not exist and doing a replace('\ufeff' '') is not an option because it is a dictionary and not a string.

```
dictA.pop('\ufeffnickname', None)
```

Comment: Is it possible you have the wrong encoding when you open the file handle?

Answer (score 1):

`unicodecsv` is designed to fill gaps in Python 2's `csv` module functionality. It hasn't been maintained since 2015, and it doesn't even officially support any Python version newer than 3.5.

Don't use it. Just use the standard `csv` module with the `utf-8-sig` encoding:

```
with open(whatever, encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as f:
    r = csv.DictReader(f)
```

(`newline=''` is there because the `csv` module needs to do its own newline handling to handle quoted line breaks properly.)